# How can I set individual USB ports on a workstation to READ ONLY in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, read-only

Is it possible to set individual USB ports on a workstation to Read-only and the others still be set to Read-Write?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for individual ports. For all ports see [How to Enable or Disable Write Access On USB Ports in Windows](http://www.ampercent.com/enable-disable-write-access-usb-drive/6264/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Even the URL indicates that's USB mass storage, not USB proper.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is almost certainly **no, that's not possible** as asked for in the question.

[USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) doesn't really have a concept of "read" or "write" any more than perhaps, say, a book does.

USB deals with [packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Communication) being sent back and forth. Some packets can contain commands for a device, such as a [USB mass storage device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class) to interpret ("report capacity" or "read data from location"); other commands are USB-generic (like "identify device"); and some types of USB devices are [practically unidirectional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) simply as a result of their purpose. This, however, is at most a property of the device's particular class (mass storage, human interface device, etc.), which is at a layer a few steps removed from USB itself, to some extent also depending on which part of USB you are considering (electrical properties, data signaling, the protocol and valid packet contents, ...?).

If you want to ensure that a *mass storage device* (which is only one type of device that USB natively allows for) is not written to no matter what the OS does, such as for example in [digital forensics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_forensics), this is commonly accomplished through a [write blocker, also known as forensic disk controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_disk_controller). These however can be fairly expensive, as they are considered a specialist tool and not commonly used outside their specific niche.

[This article](http://www.ampercent.com/enable-disable-write-access-usb-drive/6264/) pointed to by [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) suggests a way to set up Windows such that all USB *mass storage devices only* are *mounted* read-only, which should prevent mistakenly writing to the device. However, I would not put anything resembling a forensic level of trust into this; I can easily see the OS still writing things to the media, like file access times or file system dirty flags, and since it's just a registry change, it's as easy to take out as to put in.

Comment: An alternative to a write blocker is also mounting Read-Only in Linux. In the UK at least, this is just as legally acceptable for proving the data is still valid.